# Tannaka duality for $DG$ indschemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, derived-algebraic-geometry

In Lurie's [paper](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/Tannaka.pdf%7D) on Tannaka duality for geometric stacks he proves that there is a natural isomorphism
$$\operatorname{Hom}(X,Y) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(\mathbf{QC}(Y), \mathbf{QC}(X)$$
where $X$ and $Y$ are geometric stacks and $\mathbf{QC}(X)$, $\mathbf{QC}(Y)$ are their categories of quasicoherent sheaves. Moreover, if $X$ is noetherian then we have an equivalence $\mathbf{QC}(X) \cong \mathbf{Ind}(\mathbf{Coh}(X))$.

Now suppose $X$ is a DG indscheme in [Gaitsgory's sense](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.1738.pdf), that is an ind-object $\varinjlim_{\alpha}X_{\alpha}$ in the category of $DG$ schemes such that all the transition maps $X_{\alpha} \to X_{\beta}$ are closed embeddings. My question is as follows. For nice enough indschemes $X$ and $Y$ (e.g. quasicompact and noetherian components), do we have a natural equivalence 
$$Map(X,Y) \cong Map(\textbf{IndCoh}(Y), \textbf{IndCoh}(X))?$$
I believe this should follow from Lurie's result as long as the $X_{\alpha}$'s and $Y_{\beta}$'s satisfy Tannaka duality, since in that case we have 
$$\mathbf{IndCoh}(X) \cong \varinjlim_{\alpha}\mathbf{IndCoh}(X_{\alpha}) \cong \varinjlim_{\alpha}\mathbf{QC}(X_{\alpha})$$